# Category is not showing the products - Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, category, category-listing

I have in store Default Category > Master > Childrens.

When I click on menu on a Children, the page show all products normally, but when I click on a Master category, the page open with all filters but without products, if I filter something the products appear normally.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not add products from child categories automatically to the parent categories. So when you watch the articles tab in a category and you don't see any articles, the category has actually no articles.

When you set filters, you could add articles to that category by checking the checkbox for that article.

Comment: I have products with Master and Children category.

Comment: Ok. Are you talking about the backend or the frontend? I assumed just the backend. Are the products show in the frontend?

Comment: I'm talking about the frontend, the backend is ok.

Comment: I found the problem, it was a wrong file in list.phtml.Thanks Alexandre!

Comment: Good to read, that you fixed it :-) Maybe still write an own answer and accept it (takes some time until it's possible to accept own answers) so people, who come here from search, have an approach to test.